# como recorrer array de objetos y ingresar los values del objeto a un nuevo array

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

```
var array = [
   {name: 'Juan'},
   {name: 'Pedro'},
   {name: 'Pablo'},
]
```

que necesito hacer para meter los values de los objetos en un nuevo array para que luzca así ['Juan, 'Pedro', 'Pablo']?

Comment: `const names = array.map(person => person.name)`

Answer (score 1):

Array.**map()** es perfecto para eso:

```js
var array = [
    {name: 'Juan'},
    {name: 'Pedro'},
    {name: 'Pablo'},
 ]
let solucion = array.map(objeto => objeto.name)
console.log(solucion)
```